# Retry function call if return false in Angular timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, timeout

I am new in Angular and trying to implement a logic to retry function call if it returns false.

Below is my code snippet.

```
var checkHeaderPos = function() {
  if(CONDITION) 
     return true;
  else 
     return false;
}

$timeout(function() {
      checkHeaderPos();
    }, 100);
```

> I want to re-call this function again after 100ms if it returns false.

(Want to call until it returns true)

Help me to achieve this.

Comment: Use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$interval) with is similar to setInterval method.

Comment: It will not solve my problem. I must have to write some custom logic that is given in below answer. Thanks even though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another function that takes care of checking the result and registers a `timeout` with it as callback. Something like this.

```
function retryFn(fn, timeout) {
  if ( fn() === false ) {
    setTimeout( () => retryFn(fn, timeout), timeout)
  }
}
```

You would call it like this

```
retryFn(checkHeaderPos, 100)
```

With a little tweak to the function you can even control the timeout from call to call

```
function retryFn(fn, timeout) {
 if ( fn() === false ) {
  setTimeout( () => retryFn(fn, timeout * 2), timeout)
 }
```

}

This will double the timeout from retry to retry.